# DataMember ignored when serializing to JSON

Tags: json, vb.net, serialization, datacontractjsonserializer

I have added DataMemeber to my object properties to change settings when serializing to JSON, however it is not using them. I have attempted to change the name, as well as emitting default values.

My reason for trying to do this is I want to ignore a property if it is at its default value.

I am attempting to use the Microsoft libraries and not the Newtonsoft ones.

```
    <DataMember(EmitDefaultValue:=True, IsRequired:=False, Name:="addressTable")> Public Property addressTable() As String
        Get
            Return _AddressTable
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _AddressTable = value
        End Set
    End Property


Public Function gObjToStr(ByVal InputObject As Object) As String

    Dim stream1 As New IO.MemoryStream
    Dim ser As Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer = New Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(InputObject.GetType)

    ser.WriteObject(stream1, InputObject)
    stream1.Position = 0

    Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(stream1)
    Dim OutString As String = Nothing

    Return sr.ReadToEnd

End Function
```

Comment: Can you also post the code for Serialization or are you using WCF ?

Comment: Updated with serialization code

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `EmitDefaultValue` attribute from the Property `addressTable`.

Basically, `EmitDefaultValue` *tells the serialization engine whether to serialize the default value for a field or property being serialized*.

The default value for `EmitDefaultValue` is true, so even if a property has a default value it would be serialized. As per your requirement, if you need to ignore a property, if it has default value then you need to add attribute `EmitDefaultValue` to the Property and set the value as false,  `[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue =false)]`. In the code posted above, you have set the `EmitDefaultValue = true`, hence it is generating the `addressTable` in Serialization.

Also, `IsRequired` *instructs the serialization engine that the member must be present when reading or deserializing*. So you should be careful with usage of both Attributes `EmitDefaultValue` & `IsRequired`. The default value for `IsRequired = false`. So you can't have a combination like `EmitDefaultValue=false` and `IsRequired=true`, in this case Serialization engine would throw an exception.

Comment: I was treating Emit like Omit..... I think I need a vacation. Thank you that worked.

Comment: it only work if you also add `<Runtime.Serialization.DataContract>` to the class itself